# .toggleclass как использовать через <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#toggleClass").click(function () {
  $('#hello2').toggleClass('newClass');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="toggleClass">Выбор оплаты</a>
```

Не работает (
знаю что надо через  но к сожалению использовать внутри формы не могу его( как можно использовать .toggleclass через

Answer (score 2):

Как то не понятно что за элемент с id `hello2` ? Вы питаетесь добавить класс элементу которого не существует.

Вот примерно так работает все.

```js
$("#toggleClass").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('newClass');
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="toggleClass">Выбор оплаты</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо! в библиотеке проблема была(